# make elasticsearch return objects that have all fields

Tags: elasticsearch

I am running an elasticsearch query to return objects that have certain fields. Using sourcefilter works like an OR operator but I'd like to only have all that have the fields and not some fields. How do I do that?

```
{
"_source": {
        "includes": ['user.screen_name','entities.hashtags.text']            
        "excludes": ['retweeted', ]
},
"query":{
    "match_all":{}
```

}

What should I include so that this query returns where there is user.screen_name AND entities.hashtags.text ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#query-dsl-exists-query) for this purpose.

The below query should work in your case:

```
GET sample/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "user.screen_name"
          }
        }, 
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "entities.hashtags.text"
          }  
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```